# Unable to achieve expected result when clicking copy button

Tags: cypress

I am trying to click a COPY button from a modal but it does not copy the content when running the test but when I tried it manually it is working fine:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors? and also please add the entire code into the question and not screenshot.

Comment: @AlapanDas, updated the post. I only encountered an error for asserting if the toaster notification would be visible upon clicking the COPY button. However, when I try to click the said button in the test runner it does not display the notification but when I tried it manually it works fine.

Comment: How about you use `cy.get('button').contains('Copy', {matchCase: false}).click()` or `cy.contains('button', 'Copy', {matchcase: false}).click({force: true})` ?

Comment: still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue a few days ago and the only thing that worked for me was using `realClick()` instead of just `click()`.